# Mocked method returns null instead of expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to use Mockito for testing EJB. The `get()` method returns with the result of a database query and the `transformedGet()` does the business logic in the session bean.

If the `mockFoo.get()` is called directly, it works as expected.
But when the `mockFoo.transformedGet()` calls the `get()` method it returns with null, instead of the expected value.

I would like to test the business logic, and isolate the database query. Is it possible to do this with Mockito?

Class to test:

```
public class Foo {
    public String get() {
         return "get";
    }

    public String transformedGet() {
        return "transformed" + get();
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void mockitoTest() {
    Foo mockFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    String expected = "test";

    Mockito.when(mockFoo.get()).thenReturn(expected);

    String actual = mockFoo.get();
    Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
    String transformed = mockFoo.transformedGet();
    Assert.assertEquals(transformed, "transformed" + expected);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mocking the class under test. All methods are mocked, inclusing transformedGet(), which returns null by default since you didn't tell Mockito what it should return.

The best practice would be to have get() in a separate class, injected into the class under test. Your test would mock this injected dependency, and not the class under test.

You can also use a [spy](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) or a [partial mock](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16), as explained in the documentation, but this isn't ideal.